# connect with proxy in python-socketio

Tags: python, python-socketio

I am using `python-socketio` and I want to use a proxy (http proxy) in `socketio`, but I cannot figure out how to do that. I've searched, but I don't know enough to find the answer...

For example, is there a method or property or something like this:

```py
# assume that sio = socketio.Client()

sio.connect(url='some-url',transports=["websocket"], proxy = "some-proxy-url")

#or

sio.wait(proxy="proxy-url")

#or

sio.proxy() = "proxy-url"

#or

sio = socketio.Client(proxy="proxy-url")
```

Comment: You can pass an initialized requests (sync) or aiohttp (async) session object in the `http_session` argument. Documentation: https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#socketio.Client

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg can you write an example? i try but i still can not use it

Comment: I don't have an example to share, sorry. If you configure your requests or aiohttp client to work with your proxy then socketio should work as well, this isn't something that socket.io needs to know about.